# Cocoa - NSScrollView with large number of items

Tags: cocoa, memory, nsimage, nsscrollview

I have an `NSScrollView` to which I'm adding a bunch of `NSViews` that have an `NSImage` subview.  Basically it is a long row of thumbnails contained in a scroll view.

Everything works great... until there are thousands of images in the scroll view (since there is no creation of separate thumbnail images, the images are large but downsized to thumbnail size).

It seems the best thing to do would be to dealloc the images that aren't currently shown in the scroll view, and load them back into memory as they come into view.  Does `NSView` support this type of notification (similar to `viewWillAppear:` and `viewWillDisappear:` on iOS).

Also, in ARC mode, how do explicitly tell the OS to unload an image? Will setting the `NSImage*` to nil do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach would be to create a custom `NSView` subclass that owns the image subviews:

- Code your `drawRect:` method so that only those images that intersect with the *dirtyRect* are drawn.
- Embed your custom view as the subview of the `NSScrollView`.
- As images are added/removed (if this is even possible) you'll want to recalculate your view size and call `[super setFrameSize:]` so the scroll view knows to change the scroll bar length etc.
- Override `setFrameSize` to re-layout and modify the size, on the way through, if you change the layout when the view is resized (if you have the concept of layout in your view).

You don't say in your question what issues you are facing; are they memory or performance (or both)?  I don't think continually releasing and reallocating the subimages will help you either way.